# HTML/PHP | Как не перебивать один get запрос другим

Tags: html, get

Есть 2 формы, если отправить запрос с одной а потом с другой в адресной строке будет только запрос второй формы. Нужно что-бы 1 запрос не уничтожал другие а отображался через "&" как это сделать?

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <button type="submit" name="first-info" value="info1">Отправить</button>
</form>
<form action="" method="get">
    <button type="submit" name="second-info" value="info2">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: вероятно дать понять потенциальным советчикам - для чего это нужно

Comment: @sterx для совмещения пагинации и поиска

Comment: @Dasderdas Пагинация и поиск делаются в одной форме в одном гет запросе всегда. Как с этим связаны две формы - не ясно

Comment: передавайте offset (page) в hidden поле ОДНОЙ формы. зачем для пагинации отдельная форма действительно непонятно

Answer (score 0):

Нужно объединить все в одну форму.

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <button type="submit" name="first-info" value="info1">Отправить</button>
    <button type="submit" name="second-info" value="info2">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Button конечно отправится только один, но текст и чек боксы сложатся

Comment: Не выйдет, формы должны быть разные

Comment: Тогда пишите яваскрипт